# Is it possible to make a dual Windows 7 & Ubuntu bootable USB flash drive?

Tags: 12.04, usb, windows-7

I am wondering if it is possible to make a dual bootable USB flash drive with both Ubuntu and a Windows 7 on it, so I can choose which OS to use on startup?

Answer (score 1):

In case of Ubuntu - yes, in case of Windows - no, because you will crash the license, and windows will glitch for all time

Answer (score 0):

You can make a live usb of multiple Linux operating systems.Have a look at [MultiSystem](http://liveusb.info/dotclear/).However it appears that it is not an open source software.

Comment: thx for the answers